# How to make sure that packages are imported, when importing a local .py file

Tags: python, package, python-import

When importing a local python file, how do I make sure that the necessary packages are also imported?

Example:

I want to import myfunction from pythonfile, which is located in the same directory

```
from pythonfile import myfunction
```

But myfunction uses library. How do I make sure library is imported correctly?

```
## this is pythonfile

import library

def myfunction():
    library.dosomething()
```

I guess I could just put the import inside the function, but I would prefer not to import the package everytime.

Comment: python handles that for you. if you need to use functions from `pythonfile` any imports that `pythonfile` needs will be handled on its end. your example should work as-is, minus the indendation error

Comment: "but I would prefer not to import the package everytime." modules are imported only once.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I import the package with an alias, i.e. `import library as lib`, would that be an issue? ** Indentation edited

Comment: @Kris, but I guess a check would be made, in order to verify that the module is already imported. My point was to avoid this.

Comment: python does that for you.  why an import should be counter checked then??